# How to save uploaded images in a custom folder of pub media in magneto 2?

Tags: magento2, php, image-upload, media-images

I want to provide a provision for uploading an image the image, should move/save to the custom folder which I have created in pub/media please be specific while explaining the code it will help me a lot thank you!

Comment: Follow this one : https://www.rohanhapani.com/how-to-upload-image-using-ui-component-in-magento-2/

Comment: @RohanHapani  I want to create using a normal PHP input field, not through the UI component can you please guide me on this thank you!

Comment: Please describe more

Comment: @Msquare when I upload an image it should send an ajax call and in that, I want to send a response and save the image in pub media through which I can access the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution:

Add file upload input in your phtml

```
<li class="field upload front_img required full-width">
          <div class="item">
            <div class="image_upload front" id="image_upload_front" style="background-size: contain;">
                <input type="file" name="front_img" id="front_img" data-size="13" data-validate="{required:true}">
            </div>
            <div id="attachmentFilesFrontImg" class="attachmentfiles"></div>
          </div>
          <h3>Front*</h3>
        </li>
```

Send Ajax Request from phtml file:

```
/**** Upload Image ****/
    $("#front_img").change(function(){
        var data = $("#onlinequote-form").get(0);
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo $this->getUrl(); ?>controllername/index/addFrontImgCustomize?isAjax=true' ?>",
            type: "POST",
            data: new FormData(data),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            showLoader: true,
            success: function (response) {
              if(response.error == false)
              {
                $('div.actions').show();
                $("#attachmentFilesFrontImg").html(response.data.html);
                $('#front_img').attr("src", response.data.path);
              }
            },
        });
    });
```

Create Ajax controller AddFrontImgCustomize.php at vendor\module\Controller\Index.

```
<?php
    namespace vendor\module\Controller\Index;

    use Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data as JsonHelper;

    class AddFrontImgCustomize extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
    {
        protected $_pageFactory;
        protected $connection;
        protected $_mediaDirectory;
        protected $_fileUploaderFactory;
        public $_storeManager;

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $connection,
            JsonHelper $jsonHelper,
            \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
            \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory,
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
            \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
        {
            $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
            $this->connection = $connection;
            $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
            $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
            $this->_mediaDirectory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA);
            $this->_fileUploaderFactory = $fileUploaderFactory;
            $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
            return parent::__construct($context);
        }

        public function execute(){
            $_postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
            $message = "";
            $newFileName = "";
            $error = false;
            $data = array();
            if (isset($_FILES['front_img']['name']) && $_FILES['front_img']['name'] != '') {
                try{
                    $target = $this->_mediaDirectory->getAbsolutePath('vendor/module');
                    //attachment is the input file name posted from your form
                    $uploader = $this->_fileUploaderFactory->create(['fileId' => 'front_img']);
                    $_fileType = $uploader->getFileExtension();
                    $uniqid = uniqid();
                    $newFileName = $uniqid .'.'. $_fileType;
                    /** Allowed extension types */
                    //$uploader->setAllowedExtensions(['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png']);
                    /** rename file name if already exists */
                    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                    $result = $uploader->save($target, $newFileName); //Use this if you want to change your file name
                    if ($result['file']) {
                        $_mediaUrl = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
                        $_src = $_mediaUrl.'vendor/module/'.$newFileName;
                        $error = false;
                        $message = __("File has been successfully uploaded");
                        $html = '<div class="image item base-image" data-role="image" id="'. $uniqid .'">
                                    <div class="wallpaper-image-wrapper">
                                        <input type="hidden" value="vendor/module/'.$newFileName.'" name="frnt_img">
                                    </div>
                                </div>';
                        $data = array('filename' => $newFileName, 'path' => $_mediaUrl.'vendor/module/'.$newFileName, 'fileType' => $_fileType, 'html' => $html);
                    }
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $error = true;
                    $message = $e->getMessage();
                }
            }

            $resultJson = $this->resultJsonFactory->create();
            return $resultJson->setData([
                        'message' => $message,
                        'data' => $data,
                        'error' => $error
            ]);
        }
    }
```